Row Echelon Form - Java Code Correctness
I wrote some code that calculates the REF (Row Echelon Form) of a matrix in Java, and I was wondering if my final code is implementing the correct algorithm to solve for it (the code is similar to the pseudocode provided in Wikipedia's gaussian elimination, although it was wrong in the row swapping part). Bonus: Ascertain the time and space complexity of the code (Big O) and identify a more efficient method for determining the REF of a matrix.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MATRIX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows for the first matrix: ");
        int ROWS1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns for the first matrix: ");
        int COLS1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        
        double[][] matrix1 = new double[ROWS1][COLS1];
        
        for (int o = 0; o < ROWS1; o++) {   
            for (int p = 0; p < COLS1; p++) {
                System.out.printf("Element (%d,%d) of first matrix: ",o+1,p+1);
                matrix1[o][p] = in.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nInput matrix:");
        MatrixPrint(matrix1, ROWS1, COLS1);
        
        System.out.println("\nRow echelon form:");
        MatrixPrint(REF(matrix1, ROWS1, COLS1),ROWS1,COLS1);
        in.close();

    }
    
    public static void MatrixPrint(double[][] matrix, int rows, int cols) {
        for (int n = 0; n < rows; n++) {
            for (int o = 0; o < cols; o++) {
                System.out.printf("%,.3f ", matrix[n][o]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static double[][] REF (double[][] matrix, int rows, int cols) {
        /* matrix[i][j] (m x n)
        if row swap performed, multiply final determinant by -1
        if multiply row by scalar, multiply determinant by same scalar */
        int h = 0, k = 0; // initialization of pivot row and column respectively
        
        while (h < rows && k < cols) {
            double[] columnArray = new double[rows - h];
            for (int i = h; i < rows; i++) {
                columnArray[i - h] = matrix[i][k];
            } // find corresponding columns for each k
            int i_max = h + getArgMax(columnArray);
            
            if (matrix[i_max][k] == 0) { //there is no max here, move to the next column
                k++;
            } else {
                if (i_max > h && matrix[h][k] == 0) { // swap current pivot with max only if the max is "below" the pivot
                    matrix = exchangeAnyTwoRows(matrix, h, i_max);
                }
                for (int i = h + 1; i < rows; i++) {
                    double f = matrix[i][k] / matrix[h][k];
                    for (int j = k; j < cols; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] -= f * matrix[h][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            h++; // move to next pivot row
            k++; // move to next pivot column           
        }
        return matrix;
    }
    public static double getMax(double[] array) {
        double max = Math.abs(array[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(array[i]) > max) {
                max = Math.abs(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }   
    public static int getArgMax(double[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (getMax(array) == array[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static double[][] exchangeAnyTwoRows(double[][] matrix, int K, int L) {
        double[] temp = matrix[K];
        matrix[K]= matrix[L];
        matrix[L] = temp;       
        return matrix;
    }  
}
```

